# After selecting image via UIImagePickerController none of the IBAction work in toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working with Swift 2 in xCode 7. Building a single view app. What I'm trying to do is allow the user to access their photo library, select an image, and then record some audio.

I setup an UIImageView view for where the selected photo will go and then a UIToolbar with three UIBarButtonItems: Image , Record, Play. Clicking on 'Image' will bring up the user's photo library to pick a photo from.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgSlctBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var recordBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var playBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!

    var soundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
    var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    var fileName = "micFlagRecording"
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var newFileName = ""
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func getCacheDirectory() -> String {
    . . . 
    }

    func saveFileReference() {
    . . .
    }

    func newFileURL() -> NSURL {
    . . .
    }

    func getFileURL() -> NSURL {
    . . .  
    }

    func setupRecorder() {
    . . .    
    }

    func preparePlayer() {
    . . .    
    }

    @IBAction func record(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("record started")
        if sender.title == "Record" {
            soundRecorder.record()
            recordBtn.title = "Stop"
        } else {
            soundRecorder.stop()
            recordBtn.title = "Record"
            playBtn.enabled = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if sender.title == "Play" {
            recordBtn.enabled = false
            sender.title = "Stop"
            preparePlayer()
            soundPlayer.play()
        } else {
            soundPlayer.stop()
            sender.title = "Play"
            recordBtn.enabled = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func initImgSlct(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playBtn.enabled = false
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        setupRecorder()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

What happens when I try out this code is recording and play back work just fine. However, after I select an image from the photo library by clicking "Image" (which calls the IBAction func initImgSlct) the UIBarButtonItems are still clicking but none of the IBActions are triggered.

I was thinking the issue has to do with my dismissViewController on ImagePickerController is not returning delegation back to my ViewController? I'm new to Swift so that could be way off.

Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: look at the view debugger after u dimiss the picker. See what is covering the toolbar.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the debugger view hierarchy before and after selecting a photo. They both look the same. Nothing is overlapping the toolbar after I select a photo. To clarify, after I select an Image the UIBarButtonItems are still clicking but none of the IBActions are triggered.

Comment: In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, I think it should be `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)` rather than (implied) `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated( . . . ) which didn't work either.